# Tomcat hangs due to large requests

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, grails

I have a Grails application which is deployed in Apache Tomcat server. Everything works fine but sometimes the application receives around 100-200 requests in succession(Due to an API integration and these many requests are sent by the API to my application that too within a few minutes and not by my application to the API) and tomcat starts to hang(There are no errors though).

The request is mostly to perform some small DB updates from the data sent by the API used.

Is there a way i can handle this? Any jvm setting or any code changes to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to increase the max threads in your tomcat server

```
<Connector port="8080" address="localhost"     
     maxThreads="250" <!-- here -->
      maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
     connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20160410090326/http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_tomcat_performance_in_production

Comment: Can we increase this value to around 400 or 500. Will it have any memory implications?

Comment: it really depends try to work on a staging server first before putting in on the production.

Comment: Thanks, I check and see how it goes

Comment: I tried before around 1000 MaxThreads it works fine as we didn't reach  that peak situation but if you are running in a 4 core(3.x GHZ) or more server i think it would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Before increasing the NIO thread limit, make sure your `I'O` operations able to handle the load. If `I/O` operations unable to handle the load thread will be pilled up quickly again it and will hit the threshold of NIO thread limit due to Backpressure from DB.